# I need to know what this code does

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I see this code in the "guestbook" page source code on a website:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".view_comments").click(function() {

            var ID = $(this).attr("id");

            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "guestmsg/viewajax.php",
                data : "msg_id=" + ID,
                cache : false,
                success : function(html) {
                    $("#view_comments" + ID).prepend(html);
                    $("#view" + ID).remove();
                    $("#two_comments" + ID).remove();
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

I use Firefox no script extension and I am not able to open "View another message".

Comment: this code sends message ID to guestmsg/viewajax.php script, gets back the comments on it and then prepends them to view_commentsX (X for ID) element that has that id in the html. and then it removes elements with id viewX and two_commentsX

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't exist to clear your concerns about what your browser is executing.

Comment: @DanSaltmer for that I use NoScript ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code check for new comments. If you want to be able to see messages, you have to turn off your extension temporarily